# Two dimensional array as item of dictionary

Tags: arrays, excel, dictionary, vba

I would like to populate a dictionary with several properties of an item. Example:

[image: Sample data]

I was thinking of having *Item 1* and *Item 2* as `Dictionary` keys with an `array` that would hold its properties. 
I would need to be able to separately access each property of an item so concatenating them as one string is not an option.

I'm thinking about something like the below **pseudo-code**:

```
    With Workbooks("testing macro").Sheets(test).Range("D7:G8")

     For i = 1 To .Rows.count

        items_dict.Add Key:=.Cells(i, 1).Value, _
 Item:= array(i,1)= .cells(i,2).value array(i,2)=.cells(i,3).value array(i,3).cells(i,4)
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: why not use a class and a collection?

Comment: The way I defined the dictionary isn't working code. Is just wrote that to describe what I think needs to happen. I'm not using a collection because I need the Key feature of a dictionary to selectively pull data. i.e. be able to get information about a specific item I have in mind.

Comment: you can do that w/ a collection.  I'll post an example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example using a class and a collection (basically modified from the examples [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx):

Class is pretty simple (class name is Employee):

```
Option Explicit

Private pName As String
Private pAddress As String
Private pSalary As Double

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property
Public Property Let Name(Value As String)
    pName = Value
End Property
Public Property Get Address() As String
    Address = pAddress
End Property
Public Property Let Address(Value As String)
    pAddress = Value
End Property
Public Property Get Salary() As Double
    Salary = pSalary
End Property
Public Property Let Salary(Value As Double)
    pSalary = Value
End Property
```

Here is the test code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim counter As Integer

    Dim Employees As Collection
    Dim Emp As Employee

    Dim currentEmployee As Employee


    Set Employees = New Collection

    For counter = 1 To 10
        Set Emp = New Employee

        Emp.Name = "Employee " & counter
        Emp.Address = "Address " & counter
        Emp.Salary = counter * 1000

        Employees.Add Emp, Emp.Name

    Next counter

    Set currentEmployee = Employees.Item("Employee 1")


    Debug.Print (currentEmployee.Address)

End Sub
```

As you can see, I'm adding items to my class specifying a key:

```
Employees.Add Emp, Emp.Name
```

which you can then use to pull directly from without looping.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do what you originally proposed by using the `Array` function to create a Variant array. If your data structure is getting this elaborate, it's usually better to have a data model class as in @sous2817's answer. But this technique is useful for adhoc, throwaway code.

```
Dim r As Range

For Each r In ['[testing macro.xlsx]test'!D7:G8].Rows
    ItemsDict.Add r.Cells(1).Value, Array( _
        r.Cells(2).Value, _
        r.Cells(3).Value, _
        r.Cells(4).Value)
Next
```

Comment: That's a nice way to go about it. What's happening with the array as we move through the rows ? We're basically doing `Array(Value1,Value2,Value3)`, is the data just being overwritten ? What would happen when we move to the second row ? Also, how does VBA know to set `Array[1] = "Value1"` and not call `Array[1]`?

Comment: Array(1, 2, 3) creates a new array with elements 1,2,3. Each time through the for loop, Array() is called, so a new array is created for each row. You would index the dict like Debug.Print ItemsDict("Key")(0) (to get the first element). Not sure what your last question is.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate you coming back and understanding the other approaches. A lot of people run off after they get some working code.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach - dictionary of dictionaries:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub nestedList()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long, x As Variant, y As Variant, z As Variant
    Dim itms As Dictionary, subItms As Dictionary   'ref to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set itms = New Dictionary

    For i = 2 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        Set subItms = New Dictionary         '<-- this should pick up a new dictionary

        For j = 2 To ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count

            '           Key: "Property 1",          Item: "A"
            subItms.Add Key:=ws.Cells(1, j).Value2, Item:=ws.Cells(i, j).Value2

        Next

        '        Key: "Item 1",              Item: subItms
        itms.Add Key:=ws.Cells(i, 1).Value2, Item:=subItms

        Set subItms = Nothing                '<-- releasing previous object

    Next
    MsgBox itms("Item 3")("Property 3")      'itms(ws.Cells(3, 1))(ws.Cells(1, 3)) = "I"
End Sub
```

.

It adjusts dynamically to total number of rows and columns, so there is no maintenance needed

The benefit over collections is that you can check if **keys exist** or not

The slowest part is adding all items to dictionaries, but when done accessing the items is very fast

**Note**: Dictionaries cannot have duplicate Keys

.

**Edit**:

If you step through the code you'll be able to see the following objects:

[image: DictionaryOfDictionaries]

.

If you replace the MsgBox line with the following:

```
For Each x In itms.Keys
    For Each y In itms(x)
        If InStr(y, 1) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print vbNullString
            Debug.Print x & " ---> Key: '" & y & "' -> Item: '" & itms(x)(y) & "'"
        Else
            Debug.Print vbTab & vbTab & " -> Key: '" & y & "' -> Item: '" & itms(x)(y) & "'"
        End If
    Next
Next
```

You will get:

```
Item 1 ---> Key: 'Property 1' -> Item: 'A'
         -> Key: 'Property 2' -> Item: 'B'
         -> Key: 'Property 3' -> Item: 'C'

Item 2 ---> Key: 'Property 1' -> Item: 'D'
         -> Key: 'Property 2' -> Item: 'E'
         -> Key: 'Property 3' -> Item: 'F'

Item 3 ---> Key: 'Property 1' -> Item: 'G'
         -> Key: 'Property 2' -> Item: 'H'
         -> Key: 'Property 3' -> Item: 'I'
```

or type

```
For Each x In itms.Keys: For Each y in itms(x): Debug.Print x & " -> " & y & " -> " & itms(x)(y): Next: Next
```

in the Debug window

Comment: `subItms.Add Key:=ws.Cells(1, j).Value2, Item:=ws.Cells(i, j).Value2` The first loop sets `Property 1` => `A` , `Property 2` => `B` , `Property 3` => `C`. However, the second one sets `Property 1` => `D` , `Property 2` => `E` , `Property 3` => `F`. What line is telling it that these Properties belong to Item 2 not Item 1 ?

Comment: The 2 nested For loops make the distinction between the dictionaries: The outer loop creates the main dictionary, while the inner loop creates multiple sub-dictionaries. The line that shows what properties belong to the main dictionary is `itms.Add Key:=...` (object named "itms" is the top level dictionary). I'll add an image of the structure to make it clearer

Comment: It seems to me that after you're done with Item 1's loop, you're going back to setting sdict("Property 1") when it's already set. I'm also getting a key already in use error for code that mimics your logic. Edit: It seems that me that you're not creating more than one sub-dictionary.

Comment: I copied pasted your code as-is this time. I still get the error "This key is already associated with an element of this collection". This agrees with my understanding of how this is running, you're using the same dictionary during the second loop and hence you can't use the same `Keys` which are Property 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: I'm glad you tried it out, but the problem is caused by the data you used: on the sheet, use exactly the same data in your post: A, B, C, then D, E, F, then G, H, I. and it will work. The error `"This key is already associated with an element of this collection"` is caused by your test data having *duplicate keys* (like "Item 1", "Item 2", ..., "Item 1" again). I will make an edit to mention that *dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys* (dictionary Items can be duplicated, but the keys must be unique)

Comment: I'm using the same data in the picture I posted, I made a whole new workbook with only your code to test it. `cell(1,j)` in `subItms.Add Key:=ws.Cells(1, j).Value2, Item:=ws.Cells(i, j).Value2` has only three values throughout the loop (Property 1 through 3). You're using that as a key, hence when you finish with Item 1 and start with Item 2, you're reusing Property 1 through 3 as keys in the same `subItms` dictionary which already has those keys.

Comment: I got it (finally) - For me the code works fine, but for you is not releasing the previously used subItms dictionary. I'll check on how to prevent that from happening. What version of Excel are you using (just curious)

Comment: Office 2013. If in your version it's releasing the previously used subItms how are they saved at all at the end of the Macro ?

Comment: Not sure if 2013 works differently but for 2010 all objects are as I'd expect them, however I added `Set subItms = Nothing` before moving on to the next I (Item 2)

Comment: But if you do that how is anything saved? Edit: Our goal is to populate the dictionaries with values, but now you're emptying it before we can add the rest of the values.

Comment: Once added to the main dictionary as an Item, the populated sub dictionaries will still contain all data (that's the entire purpose of this logic - create a memory mapping of all data using dictionaries containing other dictionaries as items where data can be accessed in a very convenient way: `itms(ws.Cells(3, 1))(ws.Cells(1, 3)) = "I"` (using other loops, or just using the header names as the key for the main dictionary, and row headers to access the data contained in sub dictionaries. (I've implemented previous applications like this)

Comment: When we do `Set subItms = Nothing` we are just releasing a reference to an existing object; that object is now part of the main dictionary, so it's not an object without a reference (ready to be discarded by the garbage collection). It's still accessible through the dictionary hierarchy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88644/discussion-between-newdimension-and-paul-bica).

Comment: You reset the dictionary using `Set subItms = New Dictionary` INSIDE the loop! That was my problem. I didn't realize that this was inside the loop resetting the dictionary and allowing us to use the same `Keys` on a, now, brand new dictionary.

Comment: I should have pointed it out earlier (I'm too used to it), but yes, that's the most important aspect of it