# How to set up dictionary within dictionary for 2D array of unique values?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, dictionary

I am trying to get unique Country names along with any unique Fruits for that particular country (kind of like table below).  I tried using 2D array but it was getting complicated.

[image]

End result with plan to put Country in one combobox that populates 2nd combobox with Fruit when selected.

[image]

I saw someone recommend a dictionary inside a dictionary but I'm having difficulty understanding the concept.  I've tried multiple ways to set up the Text dictionary but I keep getting an `Argument Not Optional` or `Object Required` error.  Am I just getting the syntax wrong or is there a fundamental problem with what I'm trying to do?

**Edit**
In case anyone ever is trying to do this I realized it's much easier to just join the texts together and then split them into an array when you need them.  See below:

```
Dim Arr As Variant
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim newRng As Range
Dim name As String
Dim text As String
Dim j As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim dcName As Scripting.Dictionary

Set dcName = New Scripting.Dictionary
Set rng1 = tbl.ListColumns("Name1").DataBodyRange
Set rng2 = tbl.ListColumns("Name5 Text").DataBodyRange
Set newRng = Range(rng1, rng2)

Arr = newRng

For i = 1 To 10 Step 2
    For j = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        name = Arr(j, i)
        text = Arr(j, i + 1)
        If name <> vbNullString Then
            dcName(name) = dcName(name) & "|" & text
        End If
    Next j
Next i

ReDim arrSort(0 To dcName.Count - 1, 0 To 1)
For Key = 0 To dcName.Count - 1
    arrSort(Key, 0) = dcName.Keys(Key)
    arrSort(Key, 1) = dcName.Items(Key)
Next Key

For i = LBound(arrSort) To UBound(arrSort) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(arrSort)
        If UCase(arrSort(i, 0)) > UCase(arrSort(j, 0)) Then
            tempName = arrSort(j, 0)
            tempText = arrSort(j, 1)
            arrSort(j, 0) = arrSort(i, 0)
            arrSort(j, 1) = arrSort(i, 1)
            arrSort(i, 0) = tempName
            arrSort(i, 1) = tempText
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Me.cbName.List = arrSort
```

Then you can split up the text values into an array and populate a combobox with it.  A lot easier than I thought it would be.

```
Private Sub cbName1_Change()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim selName As String
    Dim arrText As Variant

    Me.cbName1Text.Clear
    selIndex = Me.cbName1.ListIndex

    text = arrSort(selIndex, 1)
    arrText = Split(text, "|")

    For i = LBound(arrText) To UBound(arrText)
        If arrText(i) <> vbNullString Then
            Me.cbName1Text.AddItem arrText(i)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Previous work trying to use dictionary inside dictionary
Edited per comments

```
Sub GetAbilities()
Dim Arr As Variant
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim newRng As Range
Dim name As Variant
Dim text As Variant

Dim dcName As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim dcText As Scripting.Dictionary
Set dcName = New Scripting.Dictionary
Set dcText = New Scripting.Dictionary

Set rng1 = tbl.ListColumns("Name1").DataBodyRange
Set rng2 = tbl.ListColumns("Text3").DataBodyRange
Set newRng = Range(rng1, rng2)

Arr = newRng
counter = 0

For j = 1 To 10 Step 2
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        name = Arr(i, j)
        text = Arr(i, j + 1)

        If dcName.Exists(name) Then
            If Not dcText.Exists(text) Then
                dcText.Add text, counter
            End If
        Else
        Set dcText = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            dcName.Add name, dcText
            If text <> vbNullString Then
                dcText.Add text, counter
            End If
        End If
        counter = counter + 1
    Next i
Next j

For Each n In dcName.Keys
    For Each t In dcName.item(n).Keys
        Debug.Print n, t
    Next t
Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: you need to specify a key AND value so dcText.Add text (which is along the right lines) adds only a key and no value hence the argument not optional warning. And with the idea you are talking about the first instance of the key would have an associated value which would be a CreateObject to create the dictionary you want as the inner dictionary.

Comment: Thanks I thought setting the directory at the top was enough.

Comment: How would I then access the child dictionary (dcText) if I know the dcName key?  I can put the dcName keys into a combobox and get the key when it is selected.  But how do I get the item (ie dcText) so I can get it's keys?

Comment: Depends how you are adding items. If the subdictionaries already exist then you can add them as the values to the main dictionary.

Comment: See @displayname's answer for what i was describing (using early binding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will use nested dictionaries

place the following in your userform code pane:

```
Option Explicit

Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary ' this will have 'dict' Dictionary accessible from all UserForm Subs/Functions and throughout its life

' change "ComboBox1" to your actual "Countries" combobox name and "ComboBox2" to your actual "Fruits" combobox name
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change() 
    Me.ComboBox2.List = dict(Me.ComboBox1.Value).Keys 
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.ComboBox1.List = GetCountries(dict) ' fill combobox countries with countries names
End Sub
```

place the following in any module

```
Function GetCountries(dict As Scripting.Dictionary)
    Dim row As Range
    Dim j As Long
    Dim name As String, fruit As String

    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary 'change "Table1" to your actual table name and "mySheetName" to your actual table sheet name
    With Worksheets("mySheetName").ListObjects("Table1")
        For Each row In .DataBodyRange.Rows
            For j = 1 To .DataBodyRange.Columns.Count Step 2
                name = .DataBodyRange(row.row - 1, j).Value
                fruit = .DataBodyRange(row.row - 1, j + 1).Value
                If name <> "" Then
                    If Not dict.Exists(name) Then dict.Add name, New Scripting.Dictionary
                    If fruit <> "" Then dict(name)(fruit) = 1
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With

    If dict.Count > 0 Then GetCountries = dict.Keys
End Function
```

Comment: Wow that’s awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use nested dictionaries but it requires a bit more work, so you are on the right path with splitting and joining strings as dictionary items (nested dictionaries are more efficient for large amounts of data)

The solution bellow uses only one dictionary. I tried replicating your setup but wasn't sure of your Worksheet name and Table name, so I used Sheet1, and Table1 as in the image bellow

[image: SetUp]

---

**Sheet1 Module**:

---

```
Option Explicit

Private d As Dictionary 'Private variable (global / visible to this module only) 

Private Sub SetupDictionary()   'Initialize both combo boxes --- MAIN SUB
    Set d = GetUniques(Me.ListObjects(1))
    If Not d Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            With Me.ComboBox1
                .List = d.Keys
                .ListIndex = 0
            End With
            With Me.ComboBox2
                .List = Split(d.Items(0), LINK)
                .ListIndex = 0
            End With
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If Not d Is Nothing Then
        With Me.ComboBox2
            .List = Split(d.Items(Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex), LINK)
            .ListIndex = 0
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

---

**Generic Module** (Module1)

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Const LINK = "||"   'Public (global) - visible to all modules

Public Function GetUniques(ByRef tbl As ListObject) As Dictionary
    If Not tbl Is Nothing Then
        Dim d As Dictionary, fullRng As Variant, dKey As String, dItm As String
        Dim rowIndex As Long, colIndex As Long, maxRow As Long, maxCol As Long
        fullRng = tbl.DataBodyRange 'get entire table data into a 2D variant array
        Set d = New Dictionary
        maxRow = UBound(fullRng, 1) 'dimension 1 of the 2D array    (rows)
        maxCol = UBound(fullRng, 2) 'dimension 2 of the 2D array    (columns)
        For rowIndex = 1 To maxRow                      'iterate all rows
            For colIndex = 1 To maxCol - 1 Step 2       'iterate every 2nd column
                dKey = fullRng(rowIndex, colIndex)      '-> country
                dItm = fullRng(rowIndex, colIndex + 1)  '-> fruit (next col)
                If Len(dKey) > 0 And Len(dItm) > 0 Then
                    If Not d.Exists(dKey) Then          'if key doesn't exist
                        d(dKey) = dItm                  'create 1st dictionary item
                    Else   'else check for dupes
                        If InStr(1, d(dKey), dItm, vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
                            d(dKey) = d(dKey) & LINK & dItm 'append next item
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next colIndex
        Next rowIndex
        Dim k As Variant    'sort dictionary items for each key
        For Each k In d.Keys
            d(k) = BubbleSortStrItems(d(k), LINK)
        Next k
        Set GetUniques = d
    End If
End Function
```

'

```
Public Function BubbleSortStrItems(ByRef itms As String, ByVal sep As String) As String
    Dim vArr As Variant, i As Long, tmp As String, vArrMax As Long

    If Len(itms) > 0 And Len(sep) > 0 Then
        vArr = Split(itms, sep)
        vArrMax = UBound(vArr)
        If vArrMax > 0 Then
            For i = 0 To vArrMax - 1
                If vArr(i) > vArr(i + 1) Then
                    tmp = vArr(i)
                    vArr(i) = vArr(i + 1)
                    vArr(i + 1) = tmp
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    End If
    BubbleSortStrItems = Join(vArr, sep)
End Function
```

---

In `GetUniques()`, the line `fullRng = tbl.DataBodyRange` gets all table data into a 2D variant array:

[image: aeeay]

The first For loop in `GetUniques()` sets up the initial dictionary (unsorted):

[image: dictionary - unsorted]

The second For sorts the items of each key, similar to your end result:

[image: dictionary - sorted] . . . [image: initial end result]

Note: This excludes countries without any fruits

Example: [nested dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621220/dictionary-inside-a-dictionary/32621544#32621544)

Comment: Wow thanks this awesome. I’ll try to work through this to understand it. I really appreciate when people explain what the steps mean.